# How to refresh a page or refresh ngOnInit() in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, refresh, page-refresh, buttonclick

i'm wondering if there is a way to refresh the ngOnInit() function or refresh the component. i don't wanna use the pull to refresh method. i want to do it on button click or tap. Thank you

home.ts file

```
  checkNetwork() {
  console.log("check internet");
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  if(this.network.type == "none"){
    this.shouldHide = false;
    this.dividerHide = true;
  }
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: "Connection Status",
        subTitle: <string> this.network.type,
        buttons: ["OK"]
    });
  alert.present();
});
}
```

home.html file

```
<ion-card [hidden]="shouldHide">
<ion-card-header>
  <img src="img/sad.png" />
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
  <ion-card-title style="text-align:center">
    No INTERNET!
  </ion-card-title>
  <button ion-button full (click)="refreshPage($event)">Retry</button>
</ion-card-content>
```

when the connection will be available i want the page to refresh

Comment: so call the load data function on button click.. not sure what is the problem here

Comment: i; using the ionic loading plugin for a function that downloads data from server but sometimes the data downloading fails but the spinner keep on. i want a function that would restart the page so the function and the loading modal

Comment: can you share the relevant code and edit the question?

Comment: im also using a function that checks the networks avaibility if its none i want a function that would refresh the page when the connection is available

Comment: `refreshPage` function can call the loadData

Comment: suraj Good idea i did it it is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you all, this is how i managed it

home.ts file

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.LoadData();}


checkNetwork() {
  console.log("check internet");
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  if(this.network.type == "none"){
    this.shouldHide = false;
    this.dividerHide = true;
  }else{
    this.shouldHide = true;
    this.dividerHide = false;
    this.presentLoading()
  }
});
}

refreshPage()
  {this.LoadData();
}

public LoadData(){...}
```

Home.html file

```
<ion-card [hidden]="shouldHide">
<ion-card-header>
  <img src="img/sad.png" />
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
  <ion-card-title style="text-align:center">
    Pas de connexion internet!
  </ion-card-title>
  <button ion-button full (click)="refreshPage()">Reessayer</button>
</ion-card-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
refreshPage() {
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this was to present a toast (ToastController). Toast shows, toast disappears, then angular refreshes the data like it's supposed to. Toast can say "Refreshing data" or whatever is relevant for you -- in my case "New message from blah@blah". Or perhaps only show the toast for 1 ms if you don't want to clutter the UI.

Doing `this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);` "works" but has the side effect of totally reseting the nav stack, which is usually totally unacceptable.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to refactor your code structure that so it doesn't need the page refresh, using an init method or Rx's subscriptions.

In case if you need the page reload, why don't you use reload method?

```js
window.location.reload();
```

Edited:

Are you using [network.onConnect](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) subscription?

```js
// watch network for a connection
let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network connected!'); 
  // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
   // before we determine the connection type.  Might need to wait 
  // prior to doing any api requests as well.
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
      console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
    }
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: does it work on ionic 2? will it reload the whole app or only the component?

Comment: Yes it would work, since ionic2 app is running under chrome browser

Comment: This is a very bad practice since the whole application would be reloaded. Also any session data will be lost.

Comment: JoeriShoeby do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You may need to refactor your code structure that so it doesn't need the page refresh, using an init method or Rx's subscriptions

Answer (score -1):

you can re-initialise the page with calling to ngOnInit() :
this.ngOnInit();